# Mongodb - combine arrays inside subdocument and then sort

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have one document called 'Author' that includes a name and an array of books.

I would like to join all 'books'-fields (which are arrays of an subdocument) into one single array. I then need to filter out some subdocuments based on the 'pages'-field (this have I done).

I then want sort this array based on the 'released'-field inside the subdocuments.

This is my documents

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb449),
    "name":"Author 1",
    "books":[
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44a),
            "title": "Book 1",
            "pages": 59,
            "released": "2019-09-21T19:58:00.795+00:00"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44b),
            "title": "Book 2",
            "pages": 21,
            "released": "2019-03-05T20:58:00.798+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44c),
    "name":"Author 2",
    "books":[
        {
            "_id": ("5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44d),
            "title": "Book 3",
            "pages": 75,
            "released": "2020-03-04T20:58:00.802+00:00"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44e),
            "title": "Book 4",
            "pages": 49,
            "released": "2019-08-17T19:58:00.802+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to use this aggregation, which allow me to filter out books that has less than 21 pages.

```
[
    {
        $project: {
            books: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$books',
                    as: 'book',
                    cond: {
                        $gt: ['$$book.pages', 21]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This is my result.

```
[
    {
        _id: 5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb449,
        books: [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44a),
                "title": "Book 1",
                "pages": 59,
                "released": "2019-09-21T19:58:00.795+00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44c,
        books: [
            {
                "_id": ("5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44d),
                "title": "Book 3",
                "pages": 75,
                "released": "2020-03-04T20:58:00.802+00:00"
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44e),
                "title": "Book 4",
                "pages": 49,
                "released": "2019-08-17T19:58:00.802+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I´m looking for a result formatted like this.
(An array of all books that passed the filter, that is also sorted.)

```
books: [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44e),
        "title": "Book 4",
        "pages": 49,
        "released": "2019-08-17T19:58:00.802+00:00"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId(5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44a),
        "title": "Book 1",
        "pages": 59,
        "released": "2019-09-21T19:58:00.795+00:00"
    },
    {
        "_id": ("5f67b448c869aa0de8cdb44d),
        "title": "Book 3",
        "pages": 75,
        "released": "2020-03-04T20:58:00.802+00:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9RUR-FviPSP) work for what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` to flat the array, then do the `$match` to getting matching objects for your condition. Then use `$sort` to sort based on released date and to regroup use `$group`

```
[
  {
    $unwind: "$books"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "books.pages": {
        $gt: 21
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "books.released": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "books": {
        $push: "$books"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uwG-Vwoca1J)**

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i wanted